# Error while installing reaver-1.4 "no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH"

Tags: command-line, software-installation, compiling

I'm trying to install reaver-1.4 in my Ubuntu 18.04 system, but it shows this error:

```
root@rashedul-ubuntu:~/Desktop/reaver-1.4/src# ./configure
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/rashedul/Desktop/reaver-1.4/src':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The ./configure step failed as it told you; you don't have `gcc` (c compiler needed to compile; or `cc` or `cl` which are alternative compilers) - hence it cannot proceed.  You need a compiler to compile source which it repeats with the message "no acceptable C compiler found"  (*source code is compiled into the binary executables*)

Comment: how can i install C compiler in my system?

Comment: Why are you running as root? You should compile software with normal user privileges.

Comment: See [How can I install software or packages without internet offline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) since you mentioned in a comment you want to install offline

Answer (score 0):

Reaver-1.4 can be installed in Ubuntu 18.04 from the terminal. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install reaver
```

Comment: i think it's need internet connection. i want to install it offline.